# Angular 2 validation and checkbox 'required' attribute does not work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, angular, firefox, radio-button

I have a form in my Angular 2 app that has a single radio button question (with 3 answer options) in it that is required.  It works great in Chrome but when I select an answer to the radio button in Firefox, then press the submit button, a popup over the browser `back` button says "please select one of these options" and won't let me submit the form.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Some of the html code:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onNext(f)" #f="ngForm"> <!-- section form -->

    <div class="question-div" *ngFor="let question of section?.questions">
        <h3 class="question-text">{{ question?.name }}</h3>

        <!-- for multichoice questions -->
        <div class="multi-choice-question-div radio-btn-div question_div" 
            *ngIf="question?.type === 'multi-choice' && !question?.isYesOrNo">
            <div *ngFor="let answer of question?.answerDetails">
                <input
                    type="radio" 
                    class="display-none" 
                    id="{{ answer?.answerId }}"
                    [(ngModel)]="ngModelObj['question_' + question.questionId]"
                    (ngModelChange)="onAnswerChanged()"
                    name="answerForQustion{{ question?.questionId }}"
                    [value]="answer"
                    required>
                <label class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 multi-choice-label" for="{{ answer?.answerId }}">
                    <p class="q-text">{{ answer?.value }}</p>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end multichoice question -->

        ....

    <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-next"
        (click)="onNext(f)"
        *ngIf="currentSectionIndex === sectionsArr.length - 1"
        [disabled]="!checkFormValidation(f)">
            NEXT
    </button>

</form>
```

Comment: Are u sure, that you should use single radio button? That is the role of checkbox.

Comment: Could you share some of your html code ?

Comment: @JaroslawK. it is a single radio button question with 3 options to choose from

Comment: @Karbos538 I added some html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your problem. I think there is a conflict between Angular 2 validation and native browser validation but I don't find any opened issue about this (just about ng-pristine).

I suggest you to disable the native browser validation with form's `novalidate` flag, so that you will be able to use Angular 2 validation with something like `ngForm.valid` (`f.valid` in your case).

So your form will look the following :

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onNext(f)" #f="ngForm"> <!-- section form -->

    etc.
```

Here's a Plunker with a simplified example that worked in my Firefox 43 : https://plnkr.co/edit/cbIHbPX5knHPg1WvL0EH?p=preview